# Jquery Autocomplete is showing pieces of unwanted data in textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I've got a stored procedure that returns a set of 10 customers.  Each customer result contains an ID and Customer-Name.

I've got autocomplete working properly for the most part.  I only want to see the Customer-Name in the textbox.  However, as I type in the textbox, I see the letters I type, but I also see pieces of the ID appearing in the textbox.

For example, if I'm typing the letters "AB" in the textbox, and "Abe" is a customer-name w/ ID of 123456, the textbox will show me "Abe456".

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the autocomplete option "autofill" parameter equal to false.  It's false by default, but I had previously set it to true.